# Bizarre whitescreen of death issue

Tags: white-screen-of-death

I've just moved a site using 2.5.5 from my local setup to our hosting account under a sub-domain for staging but am having some odd issues.

At first the site is fine but if I visit the add-ons tab I get the whitescreen of death front-end and CP. I turned on debugging and got the following error

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/EE_Config.php
Line Number: 211
```

Disabling extensions in config.php didnt help but if I change the database user (ie create a new user and update database.php) the site comes back fine.

Even with extensions disabled, if I try to access add-ons, I get the same routine…

I have a 2.5.3 site in another subdomain on the same server with no issues at all.

I have the following third-party add-ons installed: Assets 2, Matrix, CP Analytics, Field Editor, Freeform, Google Maps for EE, Low Reorder, NavEE, REElocate, Sitemap, Environment, Health Check, NSM Addon Updater, Low Alphabet, P&T Field Pack, Playa, Expresso, CE Image

The local install is running perfectly.

Comment: I'd start with checking to make sure that the user has the proper permissions to the DB. I'm sure you've already tried that but that, or the answer Yuri gave, would be my initial approach. There's obviously a disconnect someplace and now you just have to find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is an Assets2 memory issue. Cranking the memory limit up to 128Mb (from 32Mb) seemed to solve the whitescreen of death problem but I had other issues with Assets not indexing correctly etc. increasing the memory limit solved the problems.

Answer (score 1):

My suspect is that MySQL server is blocking the user for some reason - you should inspect server logs or talk to your hosting provider about that.

Comment: It appears that this is an Assets2 issue. Cranking the memory limit up to 128Mb (from 32Mb) seemed to solve the whitescreen of death problem but I had other issues with Assets not indexing correctly etc.Just updated all add-ons, cleared caches and having another run at uploading with the memory limit lifted.